# How do I install the drivers for the GTX 1050 ti in Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, display-driver

I purchased the GTX 1050 TI, 
I went to nvidia.com and chose 
the right modelname from the 
Drop-Down menue, whereupon 
this download link emerged:

[nvidia driver for linux](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/375.39/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.run)

The name of the file is NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.run and it was 
placed into the /home/myname/Downloads Folder.

When I click onto the file nothing happens, there is also no 
textfile with a installation description.

Comment: Try as follows: from a terminal, *chmod 755 NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.bin; sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.bin*.

Answer (score 1):

Usually any linux distro has it's own application called something like "Drivers administration" in the menu, looks like a chip card. Select the application and then the system requires you password and  will start looking for drivers in cache. You'll see wich drivers are aviable for your system.
If this does not work, you can go to the directory where the driver file is, open it in the terminal (right clic in a blank space of the window)and type:

```
./configure
```

then

```
make
```

then

```
make install
```

Good luck, and welcome to the GNU/Linux world!

---

Edit:
As MariusMatutiae said, what you have is a .run file. You can double click and let it run, o you can open a terminal and type the file name to sse what is running, but it'll install everything bay itself.
Thank you, MariusMatutiae! I missed that detail

Comment: The file above is just a self-installing POSIX shell. No need for compilation.